# Как открыть клавиатуру без ввода на андроид?

Tags: unity3d

В Unity добавлена `inputfield`. Когда я нажимаю на андроид ,  клавиатура открывается вместе с **вводом** . Как открыть только **клавиатуру** без ввод на андроид ?

Comment: А что ты предполагаешь под вводом?

Comment: Когда нажимаю на созданную `inputfield`   клавиатура  открывается c новой страница